# Segmentation fault using malloc/struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am trying to code an easy list in C, which is able to store numbers.
With number `SIZE`, an index will be calculated and the numbers have to be stored in a kind of linear list at the array index.
However, sometimes I get a "segmentation fault", like 2 of 10 tries the output is correct.
I've gone a long search, but I couldn't find the problem.
Please keep in mind that my "solution" isn't implemented fully, so currently it's only working when the calculated index has no pointer thats stored. (Couldn't continue to code because of the error.)

Here is my code:

```
#define SIZE 3
#define NULL 0

typedef struct node_s node_t;

struct node_s {
  node_t* next;
  int number;
};

static node_t nodeArray[SIZE];

int addNumber(int numb){
  int index = number % SIZE;
  if(nodeArray[index].next == NULL){
    node_t* node = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    node->number = number;
    nodeArray[hash].next = node;
  }
}

void print(){
  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    node_t* ptr = nodeArray[i].next;
    while(ptr != NULL){
      printf("%d -> ", ptr->number);
      ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

#include "dictionary.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  insert(1);
  insert(2);
  print();
  return 0;
}
```

What causes the "segmentation fault" sometimes?
I appreciate any kind of help, thanks in advance!

Comment: this code can't cause anything because it doesn't have `main`.

Comment: you don't need to/shouldn't define your own `NULL`. What's `hash`? I assume `numb` in the `addNumber` function is supposed to be `number`? But to answer your question, invoking undefined behavior is what causes segmentation fault sometimes.

Comment: Make sure to post the code that compiles and actually segfaults in its entirety, not some edited version. The code you posted will not compile, as hash variable is not defined. You should also check the return value of malloc() for error.

Comment: Where do you init the member `next` before you do  `ptr=ptr->next;`? I can't see it anywhere near malloc.

Comment: Code shown also doesn't declare "hash" anywhere. Clearly you're not posting the code you're using.

Comment: Please show a  __[mcve]__ and the input if any.

Comment: My bad, i added the main.c. Right in the editor on stackoverflow, i edited the code variables just to make sure that its clear what i mean, but however ive missed one of them.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thats the mistakte that causes the error, it looks like. I thought its initialised with 0, but it isnt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just after malloc you do init one member.

```
node->number = number;
```

But you do not init the other member, there is no

```
node->next = NULL;
```

Also, in your loop condition inside `print()`, you check ptr against NULL, but that is in most of the looping the non-initialised ptr->next from previous loop.

```
ptr = ptr->next;
```

I.e. you rely on it to be initialised to NULL.
That is probably causing the segfault.

Useful background, as pointed out by yano (thanks):
Malloc doesn't initialize memory to 0. In order to do that you can malloc followed by a memset or you can use calloc.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution for me. However i thought its automaticly initialised with 0, but that clearly wasnt the case. Thank you.

Comment: @Tjatte no, `malloc` doesn't initialize memory to 0. In order to do that you can `malloc` followed by a [`memset`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) or you can use [`calloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i will keep that in mind.